# Quick way to exit terminal login attempt

Tags: terminal, bash, login

Bash `login` will usually give three attempts before giving back the prompt. Sometimes it will give many more - like today which were infinite. Using `control-c` didn't abort that process it just entered the characters `^C`. Likewise for `escape` — `^[`.

In any case, how can I abort the login without going through with three attempts or more?

Eventually it will time out with:
`login: Login timed out after 300 seconds`. But I don't want to be held hostage by my terminal.

```
Login incorrect
login: ^C
login:     
login: 
login: 
login: 
login: ^C
login: ^C
login: ^C
login: ^C
login: exit
Login incorrect
login: ^C
login: ^C
login: 
login: 
login: 
login: 
login: 
login: ^C
login: ^C^C^C^C^C
login: 
login: 
login: 
login: ^C
login: ^C
login: 
login: 
login: 
login:  
Login incorrect
^[
^C
login: login: ^C
login: ^[
Login incorrect
^[^C




^C
^C
login: login: ^C^[^[^[
Login incorrect
^[
login: Login incorrect
login: Login timed out after 300 seconds
```

Comment: Is this in a terminal window?  If so, just close the window?

Comment: @ErniePC12 that is not ideal. I don't want to force close the window because then my history will not be amended.

Comment: Where are you logging into her, and how (ssh, telnet, something else)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes ^D can also exit terminal CLIs. I just tried it on my own computer, and ^D does exit this properly.

Comment: Yep, that worked perfectly. Thanks for the tip.